# Counting from 2 in 2 then 3 in 3

Tags: c++, vector

i have this as my IT homework 
"A monkey opens N lockers .Then, he starts from locker 1 and closes the lockers from 2 in 2 (ex: 1 is closed , 2 is open, 3 is closed, 4 is open).Then he does the same thing again , but by 3 in 3. If he gets across a closed locker he would open it. He does this for N times." The problem wants to know which lockers remain open.

There is an example for N = 10 and the result is 2,5,10. 
What have i done wrong?

```
//NOTE : 1-OPEN, 0-Closed
    int a[10],n,i,j,k=2;
    cout<<"Cate colivii exista? ";cin>>n;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        a[i]=1;
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i=i+k)
        {
            if(a[i]==1)
                a[i]=0;
            else if(a[i]==0)
                a[i]=1;
            k++;
        }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==1)
            cout<<i<<"  ";
    }
//K should have been a number but i changed it.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your current result or do you expect us to build & run your program to see this? Also, if you write the intermediate steps on paper and then debug your program, you should definitely find the issue yourself.

Comment: You increment `k` inside of for loop... First iteration of for loop will have k = 2, next iteration will have k = 3 etc.. You keep on incrementing your `k`, so your `i` will become `> n` very fast and loop will exit.

Comment: @Rorschach is right. You are incrementing your `k` inside the loop, so your 2 in 2 then 3 in 3 then 4 in 4 and so on will happen in the single iteration. You should try to go through the code manually on paper to realize what you're doing wrong.

Comment: There have to be two nested loops to solve this problem (outer increments `k`, inner has `k` as a step), but I see only one...

Comment: Thank you guys. I have done it on paper and on paper everything was alright. @grek40 i have compiled it and i was geting all the numbers from 1 to 10. Thats why i posted here for help. Thanks for the help with the double loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote it, together with improving some things, exchanging C style for C++ style

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using std::cout; //not using namespace std since that one is too big
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

//declaring but not implementing here, want only to describe what it does here, not how
//at this place, you might want to write a comment that describes what the function does
void locker_monkey(const unsigned int amount_lockers); 

//keeping the main function simple
int main() {

    //initializing every variable if possible,
    //also using unsigned int since it should never be negative
    unsigned int amount_lockers = 0;
    cout << "Cate colivii exista? ";
    cin >> amount_lockers;

    locker_monkey(amount_lockers);

    return 0;
}

enum LockerStatus{ closed, open }; //using enum to make values descriptive

void locker_monkey(const unsigned int amount_lockers){

    //use std::vector instead of array
    //if created with two arguments, the first is the size of the vector,
    //the second the default value
    vector<LockerStatus> lockers_status(amount_lockers, open);

    //here comes the important part regarding your question, two loops:
    for(unsigned int k=2; k<amount_lockers; k++){ //outer one increases k
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<amount_lockers; i+=k){ //inner one increases i
            if(lockers_status[i] == open){ //more descriptive that a[i] == 1
                lockers_status[i] = closed;
            }else{
                lockers_status[i] = open;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "open lockers: ";
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<amount_lockers; i++){
        if(lockers_status[i]==open)
        cout<<i<<"  ";
    }
    cout << endl; //you forgot that part in your code - you want to finish your line
}
```

The important part was to create the double loop, that is

```
    for(unsigned int k=2; k<amount_lockers; k++){
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<amount_lockers; i+=k){
```

At least if I understood the problem correctly.

But since you are a beginner, I figured that it couldn't hurt to improve your code a bit.

Comment: `locker_monkey` should definitely not be an inline function (there is no point in this case).  I would definitely separate the code to read the input from the code to do the calculation.  (I would probably leave the former in `main`.)  `void locker_monkey(unsigned locker_count)` is a much simpler function to test and debug.

Comment: @MartinBonner You're right, changed that. Feel free to do an edit if you see something else.

Comment: @Aziuth Hey man , thanks a lot for the rewrite of the program. I rewrote mine from 0 with the advises about that double loop. I have compiled yours and mine , and they result in 0,1,4,9 if amount_lockers is 10. While the problem insists it is only 2,5,10

Comment: @AndreiGorgan So, it still doesn't do what it should? What is the result if you do it by hand on paper? Maybe we got the problem wrong.

Comment: @AndreiGorgan Rethought the thing, 0 and 1 have to be open in any case, no iteration can possibly reach them if we begin at k = 2.